# What should I do if lsusb hang without any output?

Tags: 11.04, usb

While diagnosing a problem with lirc I tried to list the USB devices on my system by running `lsusb` and it simply hang there without displaying anything. I can't even close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I have to close the terminal I launch it from.

I guess it means there is something wrong with the USB "system" and that's why my IR receiver doesn't work.

I searched on the web and did not find much about this problem. What should I try to diagnose this?

Comment: Run the command again then open another terminal and run dmesg | tail and post the errors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, first try disconnect all what you can from your usb ports, run lsusb, then connect one device, run it again and so on. Plus, more informations about IR receiver, your HW and used kernel may be helpful

you can see what kernel you are using now by running

```
uname -rvi
```